# KnockoutJS sorting multidimensional ko.observableArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, knockout.js

I'm really struggling to sort a ko.observableArray. I've been searching for solutions for the past hour, and I'm pretty convinced I'm doing it by the book.

Basically the problem seems to come from the fact that the array of elements doesn't actually exist at sort time. Each item is represented by a function which I assume allows KnockoutJS to listen for mutations...but it's not helping me much :)

[Link to JSfiddle | http://jsfiddle.net/farina/W7HJP/](http://jsfiddle.net/farina/W7HJP/)

Check out my fiddle and click the sort link. As you can see you'll get a bunch of NaN values instead of actual sorting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It kinda sorts it when you remove the function inside the sort()

Comment: Well...ya, it sorts the array...which would be great if it was not multidimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access an observable's value, you need call it as a function with zero arguments.

So:

```
var myObservable = ko.observable("Bob");
myObservable("Ted"); //set the value to something else
alert(myObservable());  //read the current value "Ted"
```

So, in your sort, you would do:

```
        this.sortItems = function () {
            this.incidents.sort(function (a, b) {
                return b.id() - a.id();
            });
        };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/W7HJP/10/

Comment: Excellent...I didn't realize I had to address it like a function! It still doesn't work, but that is possibly my sorting logic.